# Get part of JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Not sure if the title of the question is doing it justice, but here is an example. I have object:

```
var plumber = {
  name: 'Mario',
  age: 42,
  game: 'Super Mario'
}
```

I am looking for an elegant way of using either `jQuery` or `Undescore` to get key and value from this object.

```
// foo() would be desired elegant function
plumber.foo('name')
#> { name: 'Mario' }
// or even better
plumber.foo(['name','age'])
#> { name: 'Mario', age: 16 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: the second part is what you want to achive ?

Comment: There you go: http://underscorejs.org/#pick . Browsing through the documentation often helps (that's what I did, I didn't actually know that `_.pick` existed).

Comment: @FelixKling thank you, well kind of figuring out lot of things at once and this seemed like it will "omg how do you not know that question" so seemed easier to ask. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @FelixKling make it an answer so you get rep :)

Comment: why do you want it to subtract 26 from the age? ;)

Comment: @CupawnTae Hahahaha did not notice that, I'll leave it since your comment is too awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underscore.js has [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) that does exactly that:

```
var new_obj = _.pick(obj, ['name', 'age']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could approach this two ways (without either of those two libraries). You can either pass the function an array of keys or you could pass it a variable number of arguments.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/4N6FC/4/)

**Using an array**

```
var plumber = {
  name: 'Mario',
  age: 42,
  game: 'Super Mario'
}

var splitObject = function (obj, keys) {
    var holder = {};
    keys.forEach(function (d) {
        holder[d] = obj[d];
    })
    return holder;
}

var example = splitObject(plumber, ["name", "age"]);

console.log("example #1", example);
```

**Using a variable number of arguments**

```
var variableArguments = function (obj) {
    var keys = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).slice(1),
        holder = {};
    keys.forEach(function (d){
        holder[d] = obj[d];
    })
    return holder;
}

var example2 = variableArguments(plumber, "name", "age");
console.log("example #2", example2);
```

`Underscore.js` probably has its own function for this. You'd have to check the documentation.

**edit:**

[pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) is probably the most appropriate function, as per the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here, as your first example could be accomplished easily by calling:

```
plumber.name;
```

if you were unsure of what the input would be, and needed to pass a variable, you can do it like this:

```
var arg = 'name';
plumber[arg];
```

Your second example is a little more complex, for these purposes I'm going to assume you want to be able to pass an arbitrary array of keys and return an object containing the key/value pairs for each one. If you are comfortable with prototyping global objects, you could do this:

```
Object.prototype.getValuesFromKeys = function (keys) {
    var ret = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ret[keys[i]] = this[keys[i]];
    }

    return ret;
};

plumber.getValuesFromKeys(['name','age']);
```

If you want that functionality without prototyping the global Object, you could build it this way instead:

```
function getValuesFromKeys(obj, keys) {
    var ret = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ret[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }

    return ret;
};

getValuesFromKeys(plumber, ['name','age']);
```

Comment: `plumber.name` returns `'Mario'`, not `{ name: 'Mario' }`